# XAMPP as Portable Server on US Drive

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I had setup XAMPP initially on an internal drive on Windows 10. This is using the setup_xampp BAT file.

I now want to setup XAMPP on a USB (as F: drive) as a portable server, instead of on the internal drive. I have run setup_xampp BAT from the USB, but it says nothing to do.

[image]

However, In the XAMPP Control Panel running from USB, it states 'directory mismatch'.

[image]

When running the PHP application from the USB in XAMPP, I can see that certain JSON files on USB htdocs in the application directory are not being written from the database, but are being updated on the internal drive.

Clearly the install directory needs to be updated.  How can I do that?

Comment: I think I need to start over and get the portable version of XAMPP...